# Can I have a $\int x\partial x$

Tags: notation, differential-operators

is there a cannonical meaning for
$\int x\partial x$

the same way there is cannonical meanings for
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$, $\frac{dF}{dx}$ and $\int xdx$?

If so, how does this relate to the other two? What does it even mean?

EDIT: I am new to multivariable calculus and a bit confused about partial derivative vs normal derivative, though I know it has something to do with "local linearity" vs "local 'planarity'" (planarity comes with more dimensions, linearity allows for crossing out dx's, multiplication/addition nonsense of differential operators, ...)

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no common meaning to $\int x \partial x$ or $\int \dotsm \partial x$. The partial derivative operator $\frac\partial{\partial x}$ is used in place of $\frac d{dx}$ when there are multiple inputs to a function (when you have $f(x,y)$ or $f(x,y,z)$ rather than just $f(x)$), however if you gave me a $1$-variable function $f(x)$ and wrote down $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, the meaning would be clear too. On a separate note, I don't know what you mean by "crossing out $dx$'s".

Comment: Keshav thanks, also "crossing out dx's" means, if I have $\frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$ I can do pseudo-multiplication/division of differential operators, which I think has to do something with the "linearity" of the single-variable functions

Answer (score 1):

If this is a case of forgetting a $dx$, such as when people write the incorrect expression $\int x=x^2/2+C$, we can take $\int dx\:x\partial_x$ to be the operator that sends $f$ to the antiderivatives of $xf^\prime$.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate? What is $\int dx :x\partial_x$? What is $\partial_x$? Are you just saying that if one was to intentionally mutilate math syntax that they would be no longer "writing math syntax" and rather nonsense abstract gibberish which has no connection to the real world such that it would not make a difference if they deconceptualized(abstracted) it further? EDIT: first level abstractions are concepts made out of concepts.(psychology) So abstraction is a form of deconceptualization

Comment: @cmarangu You may just be unfamiliar with operator notation. $\partial_x$ is the differential operator that sends $f$ to $\partial f/\partial_x$. Thus $\int dx\:x\partial_x$ is the integro-differential operator I described.

Comment: Hello, I am most certainly unfamiliar with differential operator notation (excludign basics) can you please elaborate,

Comment: @cmarangu Well, there's not that much to say really: if an operator maps $f$ to $Of$, we write it as $O$, i.e. leave out the $f$. So $\partial_x$ maps $f$ to $\partial_xf$, which is shorthand for $\partial f/\partial x$.